# How to remove a character from string and concatinate it in Dart | Flutter

Tags: dart

I have two variables

```
String firstInput = "1.1.5";
String secondInput = "1.1.6";
```

From this I want the output `firstOutput = 115`  `secondOutput = 116`
How to remove  dots from the string and concatenate  remains as one variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [replaceAll](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) method.
It would look like `String out = firstInput.replaceAll(".","");`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  [`replaceAll`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html)with `RE` as shown below

```
void main(){
  final myString = '1.3.4.6.6';
  String withoutDots = myString.replaceAll(RegExp('\\.'), ''); "Here \\ is used to as esc char"
  print(withoutDots); // prints 13466

}
```